# C# GDI+ SetMapMode

Tags: c#, gdi+, dllimport, invalidoperationexception

I seem to be having some problems with implementing SetMapMode in C#. Not an expert in C# so Im not too surprised that im seeing errors. Even thought the compilation is fine DrawLine throws InvalidOperationException. Any ideas ?

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
static extern int SetMapMode(IntPtr hdc, int fnMapMode);

myPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
formGraphics = envMap.CreateGraphics();
IntPtr hdc = formGraphics.GetHdc();
SetMapMode(hdc, 3); // MM_LOMETRIC
formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, (2 * rect.Right - 60) - 15, 8, (2 * rect.Right - 60), 0);
formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, (2 * rect.Right - 60), 0, (2 * rect.Right - 60) - 15, -8);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing to that is setting the `PageUnit` on the `Graphics` object. From what I can see there is no equivalent to `MM_LOMETRIC`, but there is `Millimeter`.

You could probably combine that with `ScaleTransform` to get the desired effect.

Comment: You can use SetMapMode according to http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32/SetMapMode.html#

Comment: I would not trust that site for applicable usage. Try find some other sources confirming that you can indeed use it. Most of the signatures on that site is autogenerated.